# Header above LazyColumn changing height depending on available space

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to make a header above `LazyColumn` that will change its height depending on available space. Basicaly when inside `LazyColumn` there are not many items and the list is not even scrolling I would like my header to be bigger and when there are a lot of items then I would like to make header smaller, move it up.
I attach some very ugly drawing to ilustrate what I want
[image] [image]

I tried something like this (My header is just some text):

```
Column(
modifier = Modifier
  .fillMaxWidth()
  .fillMaxHeight()
  .background(Color.White)
  .padding(
    24.dp
  ),
horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
) {
 Box(
  modifier = Modifier
    .heightIn(
      min = 32.dp,
      max = 102.dp
    )
    .weight(1f),
  contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
) {
  Text(
    text = "Header",
    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
  )
}

LazyColumn(
  modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxWidth()
) {
   // my items
}

Footer()

}
```

As you can see I would like my heder height to be between 32 and 102 dp, depending on if there is place or not.

But my header either takes all the space (more than 102 dp) pushing list items to the bottom when there are just few items in the list or the list takes the whole screen pushing out header and footer. How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: @Abhimanyu the list might or might not be scrollable, it depends on how many items will be provided

Answer (score 0):

```
Column(
modifier = Modifier
  .fillMaxWidth()
  .fillMaxHeight()
  .background(Color.White)
  .padding(
    24.dp
  ),
horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
) {
  //list of the items you want to display in lazy column
  val list = listOf()
  var height by remember{
    mutableStateOf(32.dp)
} 
    val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()

 Box(
  modifier = Modifier
    .height(height),
    .weight(1f),
  contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
) {
  Text(
    text = "Header",
    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
  )
}

LazyColumn(
  state = scrollState,
  modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxWidth()
) {
   items(list.size){
  
    if (it == list.size - 1 && scrollState.isScrolledToEnd()) {
                  height = 102.dp
       }

    }
}

Footer()

}
private fun LazyListState.isScrolledToEnd(): Boolean {
    val lastVisibleIndex = layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.lastOrNull()?.index ?: -1
    val totalItems = layoutInfo.totalItemsCount()
    return lastVisibleIndex >= totalItems - 1
}

private fun LazyListState.totalItemsCount(): Int {
    return layoutInfo.totalItemsCountEstimate.takeIf { it != 0 }
        ?: layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.maxByOrNull { it.index }?.index?.plus(1)
        ?: 0
}
```